# Update SalesLine Unit price on changing the size in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 R2

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

how to approach this? Change the value of unit price in the Sales line on changing its size, As far as I know the default unit price comes from trade agreements. In this case there would be no size, but for my requirement I should assign value from trade agreements for sizes 1,2,3,4 and for 5 and 6 the the value from trade agreements should be incremented with 1. i.e

For example sizes 1,2,3,4 -> 13$ and sizes 5,6 -> 14$

I am thinking to approach this making changes in the modified field method on InventSizeid in SalesTable form, is this the right approach or is there a better way to do this. Any help appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Your task doesn't require any development. AX has standard functionality for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check `SalesTable` ***form*** go to **Data Sources/InventDim/Fields/InventSizeId/Methods/Modified** open `modified` method, you need add your logic in the end of this method.

For example (this is standar method modified):

```
public void modified()
{
    SalesCalcAvailableDlvDates salesCalcAvailableDlvDates;

    super();

    salesLine.modifyInventDim(inventDim, fieldNum(InventDim,InventSizeId), !salesLine.MatchingAgreementLine);

    if (salesLine.DeliveryDateControlType)
    {
        salesCalcAvailableDlvDates =  SalesCalcAvailableDlvDates::newCommonSalesDlvDateType(salesLine,0,inventDim);
    salesCalcAvailableDlvDates.modifiedFieldBeforeInsert(salesLine);
    }
    salesLine_DS.cacheCalculateMethod(tableMethodStr(SalesLine,itemName));

    //Your logic
    ...
    ...
    ...
    SalesLine.SalesPrice = 999; //Your new sales price.
    //Your logic END
}
```

you probably need to perform `salesLine_DS.reread();` or `salesLine_DS.refresh();` to see new price (else press F5 in form).

Comment: It is really not a proper way to hardcode the prices

Comment: @Aliaksandr Maksimau  the value 999 Clearly should not be it's only example, Must be replaced by the value calculated in their logic.

Comment: Just think that there can be thousands of products and any price change will require the participation of a programmer

Answer (score 0):

You can specify prices for product variants based on size, color etc. using the trade agreements. Please check the following [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh802994.aspx).

[image]